# MySite showing HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Tags: 2016, mysite

My all sites including mysite was working as `http://computername`

Later I installed SSL, created a new A record and modified all URLs to `https://sharepoint`. I went into MySite settings in Central Admin and changed URL to `https://sharepoint/sites/mysite` but now when ever I open mysite, I am getting message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2020 10:44:39 GMT Connection: close
```

Only mysite has this problem, all other sites are working.

Answer (score 1):

"HTTP/1.1 200 OK" means that there is no site collection at that particular URL. Run `Get-SPSite` against that URL to see if it returns a value.

Comment: Hmm....yes site collection doesn't exist!